# Model Binding - Runtime Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I recently found that if i said:

```
object latestPosts = new MyApp.Models.LatestPosts();
TryUpdateModel(latestPosts);
```

The latestPosts object does not update. This is due to an issue found [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483001/in-asp-net-mvc-generic-try-updatemodel-methods-ignore-subtype-properties). Using the workaround solved the issue. However if i move latestPosts to be a property (called Parameters) of an existing type (e.g. Widget) it doesn't update the model. E.g.

```
var widget = new Widget();
MyTryUpdateModel(widget, "Widget", null, null, ValueProvider); // LatestPosts doesn't update
```

But the following does work:

```
MyTryUpdateModel(widget.Parameters, "Widget.Parameters", null, null, ValueProvider);
```

Edit: Here's the Widget class:

```
public class Widget {        
    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    private object _parameters;
    public virtual object Parameters {
        get {
            // Code removed for brevity
            if (_parameters == null)
                _parameters = new MyApp.Models.LatestPosts();

            return _parameters;
        } set { _parameters = value; }
    }
}
```

And here's the LatestPosts class:

```
public class LatestPosts {
    public int NumPosts { get; set; }
}
```

I can't see why the initial MyTryUpdateModel didn't work for updating the whole of the Widget since it should handle complex types. I'd appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. Both work for me. Could you provide a full example allowing to reproduce the problem including how your model classes look like and what exactly is being sent as values in the request?

Comment: Hi Darin, i've edited the question hopefully with the information you need to help. Thanks

Comment: don't use TryUpdateModel/UpdateModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explaim both why the original TryUpdateModel doesn't work and why the "patched TryUpdateNode doesn't work in your case. I am the coordinator of the Mvc Controls Toolkit that contains a complex custom Model Binder, so we acquired a deep knowledge of Model Binder and of the problems behind it.

Default TryUpdateModel: it just invoke the DefaultModelBinder. Now determining the type at runtime based on information gained during the model binding process is risky, because such information come from the client and might be manipulated by a malicious user that, this way, might force the model binder to create an instance of a Type he decided....very risky...He might exploit this to force model binder to execute unwanted malicious code that is in the constructor of the "fake" type. So the general design choice is that ALL TYPES used by the model binder MUST BE DETERMINED AT COMPILE TIME

MyTryUpdateModel: it just determine the type of the root model by calling GetType, and then use this information to invoke the default model binder on this type. However, with the exception of this initia "startup" the Model Binder works as usual ....that is...the type of the properties of the root model, IS NOT OBTAINED WITH GetType or with runtime infos, but by just inspecting the type of the property of the root model...that in your case is object...that means no information.

The defaul custom model binder of the Mvc Controls Toolkit has tools for determining the type at runtime...but not  ALL TYPES..because thi expose at risks of attcks...types that are subtypes of "safe" types..for instance types that implement an Interface.

Comment: Thanks, i had hoped my initial problem could be solved using a custom model binder. I already have my own custom model binder but it would great to add this functionality to it. I've had a quick look at the code in the ExDefaultBinder.cs file but i can't quite pinpoint the exact bit of code which handles this. I'd appreciate it if you could show a stripped down version with only the code needed to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Not so easy, ExDefaulModelBinder just add extension points. You can specify a "new behaviour by writing" a Transformation Handler. Most of Mvc Controls Toolkit controls have Transformation Handlers detect automatically subclasses. HOWEVER you have to specify at wich property to attach a transformation handler! Transformation handlers   basically do the job of builting back the state of a control...but they need to attach "the control" or the behaviour at a specific ViewMdel Property. If you would like to Modify the behavior on all properties  you cant use my custom model binder.

Comment: Building a custo binder that detect classes on ALL properties is not difficult, but it needs the information of what sub-type to create in case the value is not presnt in the model and it needs to create it. For instance in your case your Parameters property might be null, in which case the Model Binder must be able to create it...but how? ...The ExDefaultModelBinder relies on information written into an hidden field when the page is rendered...then on post this hidden filed is inspected to read the information on the type to create. If you give me more infos on this point I can post some code

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback. I've just had a chance to further look at this and i've moved my code from MyTryUpdateModel to the custom binder and everything works fine. I assume the reason it failed initially was because MyTryUpdateModel only works on the initial object which is passed in. Based on your recommendations i also check that my type implements the required interface to handle this.